# Angularfire2 getting nested data from Firestore database

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to develop a small application with a Firestore backend and angularfire2 in the frontend. I created some data and now I'm trying to get the right reference to them. These are my data:

[Firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqE30.png)

I'm trying to get the reference to them with:

`this.afs.collection("accounts").doc(accountId).collection("conversations").doc(conversationId).valueChanges().subscribe(conversation => {...}`
(afs is the Angularfirestore from angularfire2/firestore)

But this results in no data in the conversation-object.
If I do `this.afs.collection("accounts").doc(accountId)...` I get the Account-Document as expected.
But I can't get deeper into the object.

I'm trying the same as described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

I'm using Firestore and Angularfire2 (5.0.0-rc.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing everything correct apart of declaring the subcollection. Your "conversations" subcollection is not a Collection, it is a "field" of the document. That's why you can not access it in the way you're trying to access it.

[image: Field instead of collection]

Comment: Oh my god! That was it! Thank you... I completely did the mistake to add it as a field instead of a collection. You saved me!